# How to change font size or use another font in Quick Look on OSX?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, fonts, quicklook

I would like to change text files font in Quick Look on OSX.

Tried to find answers on support forums but found none.

Comment: AFAICT this is not possible with the default QuickLook plugin for text files. What should be possible is using a different one that generates formatted HTML previews of text files. Maybe something like this already exists, I haven't found it yet though.

Comment: is it possible to replace plugins for QL ???

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to change the size of the font directly in the pop up (discussed [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1423732?start=0&tstart=0)), but you can change the size of the pop up box to make the text larger and easier to ready. @Howie in [an answer to a Super User question](https://superuser.com/a/212628/73637) did a great job at explaining how to do this:

> From Ars Technica Forum, courtesy of username DarylF2:
>
> [link to Ars Technica Forum](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=66722)
>
> > I figured it out, and is was actually pretty simple.
> >
> > Show the package contents for "/Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator/" and edit "/Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator/Contents/Info.plist".
> >
> > Change the "QLPreviewHeight" parameter value from "600" to your new value (I used "1000") and change the "QLPreviewWidth" parameter value
> >     from "800" to your new value (I used"1333").
> >
> > That's it.
> >
> > I didn't need to reboot or even log out and log back in for this to take effect, but I did need to open a few Pages document Quick Look
> >     previews before it seem to "take".
> >
> > As always, back up the original file first and realize you are editing a file Apple didn't intend for the end user to edit.
>
> I just tested it and it works for iWork documents only. PDF and other
>   types of previews aren't affected. I'll try to see if there is more to
>   it than that.