# How to adjust default volume of a Quick Look for any audio file in Finder in macOS

Tags: macos, finder, quicklook

I'd like to change the default value of Quick Look for any audio file in Finder.

The value for volume slide stays same if you open Quick Look for the same file consecutively. However, it changes back to 100% everytime another audio file is quicklooked.

I'm looking for a way to change this default value, as discussed for window size [here](https://superuser.com/questions/211750/mac-os-x-how-can-i-adjust-the-default-popup-size-of-quick-look-in-finder). I tried to find a *.qlgenerator for audio files in both /Library/Quick Look or ~/Library/Quick Look. Even if corresponding .qlgenerator is found, I don't think there would be a default volume parameter in its info.plist anyways.

Any other ideas?